# Xcode: Is there a way to swap an existing component on a storyboard for another

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have a complex constraints layout in one project I have copied and pasted to another. Its job in this second project is identical in all respects except that I need to replace a `UIImageView` with a `UIButton`. Deleting the `UIImageView` will also remove the constraints I worked hard to balance correctly in the first place. Is there better solution to this problem than deleting and painstakingly recreating the constraints?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is perfect in your copying view. Do the following steps to get an easy solution

> 1. Drag a UIButton just beside UIImageView
> 2. Put Same constraints as you put on UIImageView.
> 3. After putting same constraints, Just delete UIImageView.

By this, it will not disturb your constraints and you will get UIButton instead of UIImageView.

You can also do as below

> 1. Drag a UIButton just beside UIImageView
> 2. Put Same constraints as you put on UIImageView.
> 3. Hold down Option Key, drag Button to View (SuperView)
> 4. Hold Down Shift to add multiple Constraints at a time.
> 5. After putting same constraints, Simply HIDE UIImageView. Making hidden will also save your changes in code, else I might crash where you have put UIImageView references and usage in Code. You can rename UIImageView to UIButton and change throughout code also :)

Thanks

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks @v-s. I'm sure that will work, it's kind of hacky and nasty though. Just a "swap component" function will make life lots easier. Has **nobody** at Apple thought of this?

Comment: Actually its very complex. Apple creates Frames from our RULES (CONSTRAINTS). So, It might became hard for them to handle all things. I am editing one more thing in my answer.

Comment: @TheMotherofJosephBeuys, Check now. Feel free to appreciate if it helped you :)

Comment: OK @v-s, it all looks like harder work than just recreating from scratch. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Its not harder, Creating from start is little harder. Just drag, see constraints which are set on UIImageView, simply make same on UIButton, don't change any other constraint